# When is an HTTP cookie set?

Tags: http, cookies, browser

Does the browser set a cookie after it receives the header or after it receives the body? This is relevant when sending a large file in the body of the request.

Comment: If you're concerned that it might not be set in time, couldn't you set the cookie with a 302 redirect to the large resource?

Comment: I was actually hoping for the opposite behaviour. The HTTP State Management spec doesn't say anything about it http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109

Comment: It is very unlikely that any browser waits until the body is received before processing cookies from the header, except in the case of `chunked` bodies, where HTTP headers are allowed to follow the body. BTW, RFC 2109 is obsolete. RFC 6265 is the latest cookie spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think a browser would set the cookie as it is processing the response headers, since the cookie information is in there. It doesn't make much sense to receive the headers, then set the cookies after it processes the html.